# Crystal Reports is retrieving a DateTime field just with Time data

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

Here is my situation. The field I'm looking to use in my report tracks the duration of a tickets assignment to a particular group in the company. It is stored in the SQL database as a DateTime field starting from 4000-01-01 00:00:00. When I access the field using Crystal Reports 2008 it days that it is a DateTime field but it only displays the Time portion.
When I use the browse data option it shows values 0/0/0 00:00:00.

Does anyone know of this issue and potential work a rounds?

Comment: Your date field is set in the year 4000?

Comment: Yeah, it increments the duration from January 1st 4000 when storing the data in the DB but it gets stripped out when accessed by the ticketing system.

Answer (score 0):

Are you directly using the field in report or you performing any operations before using?

Comment: No modifications just directly adding the field to the report. I am going to be using the field in a formula to extract the duration information but I have not gotten there yet. Also, other DateTime fields on the same table are being retrieved properly so I'm guessing it has something to do with the the extremeness of the year.